# Cannot identify IC component marked EN=8D T3T on board

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

So, I've come across a component on a board and having trouble identifying it.  On the PCB, the reference designator is a "U", so I'm assuming it is some kind of IC however other component on this board have difficult to translate reference designators.  The markings on the component are EN=8D T3T.  Anyone have an idea what this component might be?!  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: For tracking down unknown parts, it's very helpful if you could post an image of the surrounding circuitry, and what kind of circuit it is and approximately how old.  This all gives good circumstantial evidence for the part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [Richtek RT8205M](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2206282015_Richtek-Tech-RT8205MGQW_C425772.pdf) voltage regulator.

[image]